# Weird behavior with conditional data-attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm encountering some strange behavior in ASP.Net MVC 4.

Based on some information from my viewmodel, I'm trying to set some conditional attributes like so:
`<input type="checkbox" data-primary=@(Model.IsPrimary ? "true" : null) checked="@(Model.Selected ? "checked" : null)" disabled="@(Model.Disabled ? "disabled" : null) />`

This works fine and dandy for the `checked` and `disabled` attribute, but for some reason it'll always render the `data-primary` attribute. `Model.IsPrimary` would lead to the correct `data-primary="true"`, but `!Model.IsPrimary` results in an empty `data-primary` attribte.

This leads to my first question:
*What causes this strange behavior? Is it because I'm using a data-attribute? Is it the dash inside the data-attribute?*

After that, I thought, "okay, sure, that can easily be fixed", and fixed my code like so:
`<input type="checkbox" @(Model.IsPrimary ? "data-primary=\"true\"" : String.Empty) checked="@(Model.Selected ? "checked" : null)" disabled="@(Model.Disabled ? "disabled" : null) />`

This fixed my `data-primary` attribute being shown, but somehow made my `disabled` and `checked` attributes show up empty afterwards.

My second question now is *What causes this behavior? As far as I can tell, there are no syntax-oddities in my code here.*

If anyone has any information on why razor acts this way, please respond.

PS: In the end, I "fixed" things by placing my `data-primary` attribute at the end of the input element, making everything act as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [source of Razor 2](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor/Parser/HtmlMarkupParser.Block.cs#L457) in the file `HtmlMarkupParser.Block.cs`:

```
 private void AttributePrefix(IEnumerable<HtmlSymbol> whitespace, IEnumerable<HtmlSymbol> nameSymbols)
 {
     // First, determine if this is a 'data-' attribute (since those can't use conditional attributes)
     LocationTagged<string> name = nameSymbols.GetContent(Span.Start);
     bool attributeCanBeConditional = !name.Value.StartsWith("data-", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
     ...
 }
```

I don't know why they did this but it seems like it's by design.

Comment: And this is still the case today as of .Net 6 and in my opinion this behavior is not correct or required; can anyone tell me why they have decided to do this?  The source-code comment is a good example of a not-so-useful comment since it tells you what is happening -- which you can already see in the code -- but not why.

Comment: The reason is because data attributes can be both boolean and string value, razor can't know what the intended use is.